# I can't make useEffect read input properly on conditional render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create an input component with a 'static' mode. In this mode the input gets replaced by a span containing the input value. In this question I use a range input.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const { useState, useEffect, } = React;

const RangeInput = ({
  inputID, min, max, defaultValue, children,
}) => {
  const [valueAfterStaticChange, setValueAfterStaticChange] = useState(
    defaultValue
  );
  const [isStatic, setIsStatic] = useState(false);
  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      // do this before component unmounts and when 'isStatic' changes,
      // but only when 'isStatic' is true
      isStatic
        || setValueAfterStaticChange(document.getElementById(inputID).value);
    },
    [isStatic]
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={inputID}>{children}</label>
      <span style={{ display: isStatic || 'none', }}>
        {valueAfterStaticChange}
      </span>
      <input
        type="range"
        min={min}
        max={max}
        defaultValue={valueAfterStaticChange}
        id={inputID}
        style={{ display: isStatic && 'none', }}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setIsStatic(!isStatic);
        }}
      >
        Toggle Static
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <RangeInput inputID="myID" min={0} max={100} defaultValue={50}>
    My Range Input
  </RangeInput>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The above code works. But it uses `display: none` to simulate a 'no render'. I thought that I could accomplish actual unmounting with the following logic:

```
// all unchanged until... 

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={inputID}>{children}</label>
      {isStatic ? (
        <span>{valueAfterStaticChange}</span>
      ) : (
        <input
          type="range"
          min={min}
          max={max}
          defaultValue={valueAfterStaticChange}
          id={inputID}
        />
      )}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setIsStatic(!isStatic);
        }}
      >
        Toggle Static
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Somehow my `useEffect` return function won't read the input properly now that it actually unmounts. I thought that using the return function in `useEffect` would result in a function that would run just before the component unmounts. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally, you can't access `document.getElementById(inputID).value` if the `<input>` element isn't mounted - it doesn't exist! And even it did, you wouldn't want to read its value that way. That is a very un-React way of doing things. React components should have everything they need in state and props - if you find yourself querying or acting upon the DOM directly, you are (almost always) going down a Dark Path.

Instead what you want is a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

A controlled component does not rely upon the DOM to store anything like a "value". Instead, the component merely displays whatever value that React has in state and provides a handy event hook.

I would highly, highly recommend that you read the docs that I linked and see if you can figure out an implementation on your own. That's the best way to learn after all! But if you still can't figure it out, I'll come back and edit my answer with a basic working example.

Edit: here is a simple working demo with some comments.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/controlled-input-demo?file=index.js

Note that it's actually quite simple! The `<App>` tracks the slider value in state, while the `<RangeInput>` simply consumes that value as a prop and provides an event handler for updating it back in `<App>`. `<RangeSlider>` can track its own "editing mode" value because other components probably would not need access to it (but you could "lift" that state up a level if you wanted!) You don't even need `useEffect()` here!

Comment: I like the idea of a HOC maintaining the state. The toggle button was of course for testing purposes irl my team will use Redux to maintain the state. With that in mind and looking at @helloitsjoe 's answer, is there still a benefit in using this approach instead of keeping the logic in the component like that answer does?

Comment: Well this isn't actually a HOC. But regardless, it's advantageous because when you think about it, `<RangeSlider>` should be as "dumb" as possible. How are you going to read the value of the slider? It's value must be tracked at some higher level somewhere. If you're using redux, how are you going to connect the redux store value to a slider? Maybe if you had a single slider in your entire app it would be fine to connect directly. But what if you have 10? 20? 100? What will you do, have 100 different slider components, each connected to redux separately? No, just pass the value in as a prop...

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a reason to get the value when you're unmounting, it seems like you could just keep track of the value as it changes. That way you wouldn't need `useEffect` at all:

```
const RangeInput = ({ inputID, min, max, defaultValue, children }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue); // <-- keep track of value
  const [isStatic, setIsStatic] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={inputID}>{children}</label>
      {isStatic ? (
        <span>{value}</span>
      ) : (
        <input
          type="range"
          min={min}
          max={max}
          defaultValue={value}
          onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} // <-- Set value onChange
          id={inputID}
        />
      )}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setIsStatic(!isStatic);
        }}
      >
        Toggle Static
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I though only checking the value before unmounting would be cleaner since that is the only time I need it. I know, marginal gains.